# Linked-List nth insertion fails

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have wrote a code to insert data in LinkedList. But there is problem outputting the data. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node {
  char *name;
  int age;
  struct node *next;
};
struct node *linkeslist1head= NULL;
struct node *linkedlist1tail= NULL;
void llinsertend(const char *a,const int *b){
  struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(current == NULL){
    printf("Current creation failed.\n");
  }
  current->name = malloc(strlen(a)+1);
  if(current->name == NULL) {
    printf("String allocation failed\n");
  }
  strcpy(current->name,a);
  current->age = *b;
  if(linkeslist1head == NULL){
    linkeslist1head = current;
    linkedlist1tail = current;
  }else{
    //If the list is not empty, append the new node to the end
    linkedlist1tail->next = current;
    // Update tail to point to the new last node
    linkedlist1tail = current;
  }
}
void llinsertbegin(const char *a, const int *b) {
  struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (newnode == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    return;
  }

  newnode->name = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
  if (newnode->name == NULL) {
    printf("String allocation failed\n");
    free(newnode);
    return;
  }

  strcpy(newnode->name, a);
  newnode->age = *b;

  if (linkeslist1head == NULL) {
    // If the list is empty
    newnode->next = NULL;
    linkeslist1head = newnode;
    linkedlist1tail = newnode;
  } else {
    // If the list is not empty
    newnode->next = linkeslist1head;
    linkeslist1head = newnode;
  }
}
void llinsertaftern(const char *a, const int *b, int n) {
  struct node *current = linkeslist1head;
  int i;
  for (i = 1; current != NULL && i < n; i++){
    current = current->next; // Iterate until the (n-1)th node or until current becomes NULL
  }
  if (current == NULL){
    printf("LL short\n");
    return; // Exit the function if current is NULL
  }

  printf("Reached node %d\n", i);
  struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (newnode == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    return;
  }

  newnode->name = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
  if (newnode->name == NULL) {
    printf("String allocation failed\n");
    free(newnode);
    return;
  }

  strcpy(newnode->name, a);
  newnode->age = *b;

  if (current == NULL) {
    printf("LL is shorter than %d\n", n);
    free(newnode->name);
    free(newnode);
    return;
  }

  newnode->next = current->next;
  current->next = newnode;
}
void outputLinkedList(struct node *head){
  struct node *p = head;
  while(p != NULL){
    printf("Name:%s Age:%d\n",p->name,p->age);
    p = p->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
int main() {
   printf("How many persons' details you want to add\n");
   int t;
   scanf("%d",&t);
   getchar();
   for(int i=1;i<=t;i++){
     int x;
     char name[50];
     scanf("%s",name);
     getchar();
     scanf("%d",&x);

     llinsertend(name,&x);
   }
   int x=10,y=20,z=30;
  llinsertbegin("facebook",&x );//(const int *) 10
  llinsertbegin("instragram", &y);
  llinsertbegin("whatsapp", &z);
  outputLinkedList(linkeslist1head);
  int code=1200,pos = 3;
  llinsertaftern("Dhaka",&code,pos);
  outputLinkedList(linkeslist1head);
  }
```

In the second outputLinkedList not working in either CLion or Codeblocks but it works in Compiler Explorer. I mean after adding some elements through the `llinsertend()` function then the `llinsertbegin()` function, the output function works perfectly. But when I use the `llinsertaftern()` function it shows a segmentation fault in the debugger. Suppose that I add three elements through the `llinsertend()` function and then add 3 elements through the `llinsertbegin()` function, then what is the problem of `llinsertaftern()` with the value of pos =  3. It should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Why do you pass age as `int*` instead of just `int`?

Comment: DRY -- write a function to create a new node instead of repeating it in every insert function.

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to learn to use the debugger.

Comment: You have two `if (current == NULL) {` checks in `llinsertaftern()`. The second one can never succeed because you return when the first one is true.

Comment: In `llinsertend()`, you have `if (current == NULL) { printf("Current creation failed.\n"); } current->name = malloc(strlen(a)+1);` —— Quite apart from the fact that errors should be reported on `stderr`, not `stdout`, you report the error and then continue as if nothing went wrong, which means that the assignment to `current->name` is likely to fail (crash), and definitely invokes UB, undefined behaviour.  That's never good.  It may or may not be currently relevant, but it will be a problem sooner or later — probably sooner rather than later.

Comment: You have three "insert" functions.  Each creates a node — but they use different code each time.  You should have one "create node" function used by each of the three insert functions.  You don't have a mechanism for reporting that the insertion failed (other than exiting the program if there are not N nodes in a list when you attempt to insert after node N) — you should design your code so you can report failures sanely.  Consider using the `strdup()` function to copy the names.  It is part of POSIX and widely implemented — and is added to C23 so it will be widely available.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains meny bugs. For example let's consider function `llinsertend`

```
void llinsertend(const char *a,const int *b){
  struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(current == NULL){
    printf("Current creation failed.\n");
  }
  current->name = malloc(strlen(a)+1);
  if(current->name == NULL) {
    printf("String allocation failed\n");
  }
  strcpy(current->name,a);
  current->age = *b;
  if(linkeslist1head == NULL){
    linkeslist1head = current;
    linkedlist1tail = current;
  }else{
    //If the list is not empty, append the new node to the end
    linkedlist1tail->next = current;
    // Update tail to point to the new last node
    linkedlist1tail = current;
  }
}
```

Firstly if a new node was not allocated you continue to deal with a null pointer

```
  if(current == NULL){
    printf("Current creation failed.\n");
  }
  current->name = malloc(strlen(a)+1);
  //...
```

Similarly if a character array was not allocated you again continue to use a null pointer

```
  if(current->name == NULL) {
    printf("String allocation failed\n");
  }
  strcpy(current->name,a);
  //...
```

And you forgot to set the data member `next` of the newly created node to `NULL`.

So only this one function contains three bugs.

Pay attention to that the function `llinsertaftern` can append a new node to the tail of the list. However the function does not change the pointer `linkedlist1tail`. Consider for example a situation when the list already contains one node and the function is called with the parameter `n` equal to `1`.

Comment: Since malloc practically never fails in a small program like this, this is unlikely to be the cause of their problem.

Comment: And they would see the "failed" messages.

Comment: @Barmar It does not mean that you may wirte a bad buggy code.:)

Comment: Of course, but that doesn't make it an answer to the question.

Comment: @Barmar It is enough to point to that the program contains bugs. There is no need to list all bugs. The author of the question should close his question update its code and write a new question with the updated code if some problems with his code still exist. Otherwise he should send his code to a code review.:)

Comment: The first priority is to show how to fix the bugs that are causing the problem in the question. If you want to point out other problems as well, there's nothing wrong with that. I see you've added the missing `current.next = NULL;` problem -- that should be first.

Comment: @Barmar This remark was initially in my answer but you decided not to pay attention to it.:)

Comment: You're right. I missed it because it was way at the end with no fixed code along with it.

Comment: In fact, there are no fixes anywhere in the answer, just descriptions of the problems. Those could be comments.

Comment: @Barmar It is the author of the question must to fix his code according to the descriptions of reasons of code problems.

Comment: I guess we just have different philosophies about how to answer here. If I want to leave the solution as an exercise for the reader, I don't post an answer. And remember, this isn't just for the benefit of the OP -- this is a resource for all future readers of the site.

Comment: @Barmar So now all future readers know what problems are with the code.:)